# Change all prices (numbers) with 20% on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a small HTML webpage with lots of tables displaying prices for various items (see example below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>$40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>$20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

The problem is that we would need some way to just replace all the prices with a 20% discount with the press of a button. I've tried to google different options but cant figure out what would be the best solution here.

How do I create some kind of script to search for prices and replace them with "price x 0.8", or if there's some way to enter the actual price "$40" and the discounted price "$32" and to only display one at the time.

Or is the better solution to just create an extra duplicate page with the price discounts and to link to that one?

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Keep in mind that Java != Javascript, they're about as similar a car and carpet.

Comment: is this really wordpress? if so you could run a db query

Comment: yes there is a way, javascript. As to the correct scripting to make it work you will need to provide example of the code you have been working on. In essence the sire is here to help solve problems in code, not do the coding for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and sorry about using the wrong tag (java)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following help:

```js
var currentMode = 1;
var discount = 0.20;
var reverseDiscount = 1/(1-discount);

function togglePrices() {
  var prices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
  for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    var individualPrice = prices[i].innerHTML.substring(1);
    
    if(currentMode == 1) {
      individualPrice = parseFloat(individualPrice) * (1-discount);
    } else {
      individualPrice = parseFloat(individualPrice) * reverseDiscount;
    }

    prices[i].innerHTML = "$" + individualPrice;
  }
  currentMode = (++currentMode) % 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td><span class="price" >$40</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td><span class="price" >$20</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td><span class="price" >$50</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>


<button type="button" onclick="togglePrices()">Toggle Discounts</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for and you even did all the work for me! A huge thanks :)

Comment: @thor: Not a problem. But please make sure that in the future you do provide some code snippets. :) Also, please mark the answer as accepted.